# MYSQL UNION GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, union-all

I'm doing this select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(t.text) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.from_user_id)) as usercount, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') datepart 
FROM TABLE1 t WHERE t.created_at >= '2015-08-12 00:00:00' AND t.created_at <= '2015-08-13 18:30:00' AND t.eliminar IS NULL 
GROUP BY datepart) as t
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(b.id) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT(b.from_user_id)) as usercount, DATE_FORMAT(b.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') datepart 
FROM TABLE2 b WHERE b.created_at >= '2015-08-12 00:00:00' AND b.created_at <= '2015-08-13 18:30:00' AND b.eliminar IS NULL 
GROUP BY datepart) as x GROUP BY datepart
```

this select gets this:

[image]

I'm trying to view with `datepart` grouped but I can't, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

TABLE2 only have (id,from_user_id,eliminar) and all are NULL except `created_at`, in this row I have entire 2015 year by day and hour, same format as TABLE1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(t.text) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.from_user_id)) as usercount, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') datepart 
FROM TABLE1 t WHERE t.created_at >= '2015-08-12 00:00:00' AND t.created_at <= '2015-08-13 18:30:00' AND t.eliminar IS NULL 
GROUP BY datepart
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(t.id) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.from_user_id)) as usercount, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') datepart 
FROM TABLE2 t WHERE t.created_at >= '2015-08-12 00:00:00' AND t.created_at <= '2015-08-13 18:30:00' AND t.eliminar IS NULL 
GROUP BY datepart) as x GROUP BY datepart ORDER BY datepart
```